# Attach X2Go to X Session ":0"

Tags: linux, session, display, xserve, xserver

I don't know if I'm right in concept.

But when I connect to a remote host (a cloud VPS) by X2Go, $DISPLAY variable echoes ":50", I need that variable equals to ":0" when I connect to that host.

How can achieve this?

Thanks in forward.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because I need to use Python-Xlib and doesn't work with that value of $DISPLAY and someone suggested me that this python module works with $DISPLAY = ":0"

Answer (score 0):

well it is too late to answer the original question but just for future uses I should add because only display 0 can use graphics hardware accelerator you should use "VirtualGL" in your remote sessions like VNC or X2go:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualGL

> VirtualGL redirects an application's OpenGL/GLX commands to a separate X server (that has access to a 3D graphics card), captures the rendered images, and then streams them to the X server that actually handles the application.
>
> The main use-case is to enable server-side hardware-accelerated 3D rendering for remote desktop set-ups where the X server that handles the application is either on the other side of the network (in the case of X11 forwarding), or a "virtual" X server that cannot access the graphics hardware (in the case of VNC).